# Java Stream - use subsequent map with method references, or single map with lambda?

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

What is the better practice for mapping objects in Stream API?

```
class SomeObject{
}
class SomeComplexObject {
    private SomeObject someObject;

    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        return someObject;
    }
}
class SomeMoreComplexObject {
    private SomeComplexObject someComplexObject;

    public SomeComplexObject getSomeComplexObject() {
        return someComplexObject;
    }
}
List<SomeMoreComplexObject> list;
```

1 - subsequent map() with methods references:

```
list.stream()
        .map(SomeMoreComplexObject::getSomeComplexObject)
        .map(SomeComplexObject::getSomeObject);
```

2 - single map() with lambda:

```
list.stream()
        .map(smco -> smco.getSomeComplexObject().getSomeObject());
```

And why?

Answer (score 2):

Performance ways it doesn't matter one iota.

Style wise I don't think it matters either, in that the community is not clearly committed to one way or another. Had the community standardized on one of these, there is a significant cost to breaking the mold (When in rome, be like the romans - that's usually good advice, if you care at all about writing code others can read and being able to read and integrate code others wrote; it also improves performance, as hotspot is in the end a pattern matching machine, and the patterns it has trend towards commonly used idioms).

In other words, flip a coin.